# Determining shortest distance between Isobaths

Tags: r, geospatial

I'm interested in finding the shortest distance between two 120m isobaths to determine the interaction of species during the Pleistocene.

Thus far I have found methods to plot the isobaths with package `marmap`. But have not been able to find functions to determine the shortest distance between isobaths without having to manually measure them as there will be quite a substantial number of measurements involved which would not be efficient to do so manually.

Would appreciate any advice on this, thanks!

Comment: Not a bathymetry expert, so my comment can be way off. Can isobaths be represented through 2D polygons? If so, the `rgeos` package has the `gDistance` function which measures the distance between polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the function `dist2isobath()` in the latest version of `marmap` (v0.9.1)? Its purpose is to compute great circle distances between any number of points and a given isobath. So you could get the coordinates of points along one of your 120m isobath using `contourLines()`, then use `dist2isobath()` to compute the shortest path between each of these points and your second 120m isobath.